# Why facebook API is returning incorrect response?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook API to post comment on a post and the comment is posted successfully. But in response facebook returns:

```
An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
```

When the I check the post, the comment is posted. 
Here is my code sinppet:

```
 $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $user_comment = $_POST['user_comment'];
    $user_information = UserSocials::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id' => Yii::app()->user->id));
    $access_token = $user_information->fb_access_token;

    $app_id = 'xxx';
    $app_secret = 'yyy';

    Yii::import("application.extensions.facebooksdk.Facebook");
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = $app_id;

    $config['secret'] = $app_secret;

    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);


    $result=$facebook->api('/' . $post_id . '/comments', 'post', array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'message' => 'Your message',
            )
    );

    print_r($result);
```

I must get a success or failure response because I have to prompt the user that the comment was posted or not. 
Can anyone tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for posting your facebook api credentials. Might want to get those disabled now.

Comment: I had hidden some characters in that, you better try hacking=)